# Little Schemer: length0 and mk-length

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

The little schemer gives the following on [page 165](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q&f=false) as still the function *length<sub>0</sub>*. But how does this work? It looks like the *length lambda* is being passed to the *mk-length lambda*, which evaluates the *length lambda* with the *length lambda* itself passed as an argument. So then, when `(length (cdr l))` at the bottom is evaluated `length` is just the *length lambda* itself. But the *length lambda* takes two parameters curried: `length` and `l`. So how can `(length (cdr l))` make sense then?

```
((lambda (mk-length)
   (mk-length mk-length))
 (lambda (length)
   (lambda (l)
     (cond
       ((null? l) 0)
       (else (add1
                (length (cdr l))))))))
```

Comment: correct; it doesn't. it returns the `(lambda (l) ...)` to `add1` and thus causes an error; and that's why it's `length_0`: it only works for empty lists. And the name `length` is wrong too, it should really be called `mk-length` -- as it is, in the right half of that frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Little Schemer* is building up a function that will work for lists of greater and greater lengths.  Part of the point of length<sub>≤0</sub> is that it only works for lists whose length is less than or equal to zero (and since there are no lists of negative length, this means lists of length zero).  The code that you've shown *intentionally* only works for lists of length zero.   In fact, this is even pointed out in the text on [page 165](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&lpg=PA168&dq=little%20schemer%20mk-length&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=little%20schemer%20mk-length&f=false):

> **A:** What if we could create another application of *mk-length* to *eternity* at this point?
>   **B:** That would only postpone the problem to one, and besides, how could we do that?
>   **A:** Well, since nobody cares what function we pass to *mk-length* we could pass it *mk-length* initially.
>   **B:** That's the right idea.  And then we invoke *mk-length* on *eternity* and the result of this on the *cdr* so that we get one more piece of the tower.
>   **A:** Then this is still *length<sub>0</sub>*
>
> ```
> ((lambda (mk-length)
>    (mk-length mk-length))
>  (lambda (length)
>    (lambda (l)
>      (cond
>        ((null? l) 0)
>        (else (add1
>                 (length (cdr l))))))))
> ```
>
> **B:** Yes, we could even use *mk-length* instead of *length*:
>
> ```
> ((lambda (mk-length)
>    (mk-length mk-length))
>  (lambda (mk-length)
>    (lambda (l)
>      (cond
>        ((null? l) 0)
>        (else (add1
>                 (mk-length (cdr l))))))))
> ```
>
> **A:** Why would we want to do that?
>   **B:** All names are equal, but some names more equal than others.
>   **A:** True: as long as we use the names consistently, we are just fine.
>   **B:** And *mk-length* is a far more equal name than *length*.  If we use a name like *mk-length*, it is a constant reminder that the first argument to *mk-length* is *mk-length*.

On [page 166](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&lpg=PA168&dq=little%20schemer%20mk-length&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=little%20schemer%20mk-length&f=false), the authors show a version that works for lists of length 0 or 1 (i.e., ≤1).  Finally, on [page 167](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&lpg=PA168&dq=little%20schemer%20mk-length&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q=little%20schemer%20mk-length&f=false), they get to a version that works on lists of any length.  How *that* works is described in more detail in another question:

- [Y combinator discussion in "The Little Schemer"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10499514/1281433)

You might also find the following questions of interest:

- [how to do this length<=1 more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12564013/1281433) (about page 166's *length*<sub>≤1</sub>)
- [The mechanism of anonymous function to call itself of Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19544615/1281433) (touches on the `eternity` function used on page 166's *length<sub>≤1</sub>*)

Comment: From the previous examples before that I would have thought that works for length 0 only would mean it goes into recursion forever on eternity for any nonempty list. Failing by hitting eternity as opposed to failing for dynamic typing reasons. But I do find it odd to consider "works" if it fails for dynamic typing reasons for nonempty lists.

Comment: @user782220 Yes, "works" is sort of an odd term here.  It's important to keep in mind the code isn't a continual refinement and refactoring of already working code;  the book presents a Socratic dialogue where the final code is gradually teased out after a series of attempts.